# jquery change this .post plugin to be able to use $(this) in callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins, this, .post

i use this plugin code for my ajax calls which i found on the net

```
jQuery.fn.postAjax = function(success_callback) {
  this.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), success_callback);
    return false;
  })
  return this;
};
```

i altered it a bit so i can use it better with its usage to be like

```
$("#my_form_name").postAjax(function(data){
   //code here
});
```

the only problem with this code is that i can't use `$(this)` inside the callback and that is a problem...

how could i alter this plugin to be able to use `$(this)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery.fn.postAjax = function(success_callback) {
    this.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), $.proxy(success_callback, this));
        return false;
    })
    return this;
};​
```

Read about [jQuery proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function.

Comment: i really did this and didn't work last night... weird stuff... anyway it seems to work now! Thanks!